# Fractional statistics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, anyons

A common way to show that anyons exhibit fractional statistics in 2D is by arguing that the paths of two anyons winding round each other cannot be continuously deformed to zero. This seems to assume that the particles cannot pass through each other. Why is this assumption valid?

Comment: The configurations in which the particles overlap is singular (e.g. because the interaction energies etc. blow up) so a priori, one isn't allowed to assume that things are smooth around this point. Indeed, for the existence of nontrivial anyons, the point is singular. The burden of proof is on the opposite side than you suggest. If you wanted to prove that there are no anyons because the paths may be deformed - through the coincident positions - you would have to show that it's OK to get through this singular point. In trying to prove so, you would fail because it's not legitimate.

Comment: So, does that mean that particles with no mutual interaction cannot exhibit fractional statistics?

Comment: Statistics has nothing to do with interactions, just with dimensions. What Lubos is saying [please correct me if I am mistaken] is that if you try to make a path contractible through the point where the particle at time $t$ is, you have to show that contracting through that singular point is a an allowed operation, but it is not.

Comment: Why is contracting through that singular point not allowed, other than the fact that the interaction energy blows up?

Comment: It is not just that the interaction energy blows up. The point where the particle is encodes a [phase] singularity and the configuration space is no longer smooth.

Comment: I understand that the configuration space is no longer smooth. But what does that mean physically? What would happen if two particles are moving directly towards each other?

Comment: It means that you are not allowed to put the two particles at the same place. The configuration space where wavefunctions is defined ceases to be a manifold and this is unphysical.

Answer (score 4):

We do not need to make the assumption that
"the paths of two anyons winding round each other cannot be continuously deformed to zero".

To define fractional statistics, we only require that the phase
of exchanging two particles do not depend on the smooth deformation of the exchange path, as long as two particles are always well separated during the exchange.

Two anyons can coincide with a finite energy cost.

Comment: Would you please elaborate a bit more about your last sentence "Two anyons can coincide with a finite energy cost." If I understand correctly, it would cost infinite energy to put two fermions to coincide (a poor-man Pauli principle, say), zero energy for bosons, and some energy for anyons. Is it dependent on the model, or only on the anionic statistics for instance ? Thanks in advance.